# iOS continuous FIFO upload architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, architecture

I'm working on a feature that batch processes and uploads images to a server. The general structure is:

- I have a table of images that need to be uploaded
- The image is created on the server (retrieves an imageId, etc., from the server)
- The full and thumbnail images are then uploaded to S3 from the app

I'm using `NSOperations` (`CreatePhotoOperation` and `UploadPhotoOperation`) to do this. The `CreatePhotoOperation` creates 3 child `UploadPhotoOperations` (for the 3 different-sized images to upload) and adds it to a local `NSOperationQueue`. However, the problem is, because of the dependent `NSOperation`s, if the local queue's `-waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` is YES, then sometimes the operation will stall. If it's NO, then it won't stall, but will eat up more RAM/CPU as it dumps more and more CreatePhotoOperations into the queue.

When a `CreatePhotoOperation` completes, it simply finds the next photo in the table and adds it to the singleton queue.

What is a better way to tackle processing/uploading many photos, one at a time, asynchronously? Thank you!

Note: I can provide code if it would clarify the process.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand exactly which is the problem.

Comment: Why would you do anything both asynchronously and one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the memory/cpu usage while the app is going through all the operations you could set the [MaxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/setMaxConcurrentOperationCount%3a) on your `NSOperationQueue` to a lower value. As by default this is set to `NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount`.

`NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount` will choose an appropriate value based on the number of available processors and other relevant factors.